# swing doesn't show png icons on jbuttons

Tags: java, image, swing, runtime-error, png

I have written a simple JFrame in java and added a button.
Then I added a .png icon to the button but it keeps giving me an exception.
(I don't have any problem with .jpg icons and it works well)

Here are my code and the exceptions.

```
public class Test
{
    static JFrame mainFrame;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainFrame = new JFrame("a");
        mainFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        mainFrame.setLocation(50, 50);
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\a.png");
        btn.setIcon(icon);
        btn.setSize(100, 100);
        btn.setLocation(50, 50);
        mainFrame.add(btn);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Exceptions :

```
sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: Broken file
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.pngassert(PNGImageDecoder.java:94)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.handleChunk(PNGImageDecoder.java:107)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getData(PNGImageDecoder.java:726)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:252)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder$PNGException: Broken file
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.pngassert(PNGImageDecoder.java:94)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.handleChunk(PNGImageDecoder.java:107)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.getData(PNGImageDecoder.java:726)
    at sun.awt.image.PNGImageDecoder.produceImage(PNGImageDecoder.java:252)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

Comment: There should be no difference between using a .png file or .jpg file. `Broken file` - Looks to me like your png file is corrupted.  Search the web for more information. Simple keywords like "broken png file" should give some results. Isn't that the first thing your do when you get a error message your  don't understand?

Comment: Run you code using on-line image like [so](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/0JtAl92ilo). If this works than you know that the problem is in your png file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code is fine, there's problem with your image file